# Is the following reaction allowed and if so, what is the corresponding Feynmann diagram?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, standard-model

I am trying to determine if the following decay:

$$\mu^{-} \rightarrow e^{-} + \gamma$$

is allowed. From my understanding, I believe it is allowed (please correct me If I am wrong), however I am unsure as to how one would draw the Feynman diagram to represent this interaction.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind: individual interactions obey more conservation laws than are observed globally. For example, the strong force conserves flavor, the weak force does not. This is more useful when constructing the actual Feynman diagrams because it tells you what interactions you need to reach for (in this case: at least one weak vertex).

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon#Prohibited_decays) *in the Standard Model with neutrino mass, a decay like $\mu^- \rightarrow e^- + \gamma$ is technically possible, for example by neutrino oscillation of a virtual muon neutrino into an electron neutrino, but such a decay is astronomically unlikely and therefore should be experimentally unobservable: less than one in $10^{50}$ muon decays should produce such a decay.*

Comment: @JohnRennie That looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I will add an answer, though I should be honest and say that this is just [a copy and paste from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon#Prohibited_decays).

The $\mu^- \rightarrow e^- + \gamma$ decay is forbidden by lepton flavour conservation. However when we we take the non-zero neutrino mass into account it is technically possible, for example by neutrino oscillation of a virtual muon neutrino into an electron neutrino. However such a decay is astronomically unlikely and therefore should be experimentally unobservable: less than one in $10^{50}$ muon decays should produce such a decay.

Comment: Here's a picture to go with the text:  
https://inspirehep.net/record/1374622/files/figures_muegammafeynman1.png